# How to use discrete wavelet transformation to decompose non-time series data

Tags: r, machine-learning, wavelet

I want to decompose x from the ames housing data using discrete wavelet transform (dwt) and integrate it to a linear regression model lm() to predict the sale price Here is the code I used

```
library(wavelets)
library(waveslim)
library(AmesHousing)

ames <- as.data.frame(AmesHousing::make_ames())
x <- subset(ames, select = -Sale_Price)
y <- ames$Sale_Price
dwt(x)
```

I got this error

> Error in dwt(x) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> Is this the right approach to achieve my objectives? If not, can you recommend another approach?

I want to use discrete wavelet decomposition for non-time series data.

Comment: Wavelets are meant for time series data (and can be extended to other data types, like images, yes). Why force your data into this kind of transformation?

Comment: I just wanted to see how wavelets perform as a preprocessing tool on my data in comparison with other techniques like PCA.